Atlantis shows different plan when it runs in a different workspace other than Default
I am trying to configure Atlantis to manage our terraform resources. We already have a statefile in s3 bucket as it was used by our different tool ( concourse ). After setting up atlantis, I have configured the atlantis.yaml to be
version: 3
automerge: false
projects:
- name: mainacc-rds-services-atlantis-test
  dir: mainacc/rds/services/atlantis-test
  terraform_version: v1.0.7
  workspace: services-atlantis-test
  autoplan:
    enabled: false

but on running the plan, it is showing as resouces to add. Instead it should show as
No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.

This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
actions need to be performed.

Because I am pointing to the same state file and same tf code. On locally, the plan shows as
"No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date."
What is going wrong in here.?
I ran
atlantis plan -p mainacc-rds-services-atlantis-test

It should show
No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.

This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
actions need to be performed.

but it showed as
Plan: 8 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.


Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
